# select returns 0 although packets returned, i did reset the readset every time before calling select

Tags: c, select

I wrote a ping program sending syn packet to destination ip address 1.1.1.1 port 0. I used wireshark that i saw packets returned with RST/ACK flags on. But the problem is when i use select() to try to read the socket, select() **always returns 0**. So I have no idea how to debug the program. I'm sure I **reset the fd_set readset  everytime**. Is there anything i just missed ? 
 i discovered the reply from 1.1.1.1 **returned back in 0.0003 second** using wireshark 
 the **timeout** i set is **1 second(1000 ms)**
Here is the code

```
void readloop() {
    ....
    while(nsent < 4) {
        send_v4();
        wait_for_reply(1000);    // wait for 1 second;
    }
}

int wait_for_reply(long wait_time) {
....
    result = recving_time(...);
    if(result < 0)  // because time out
        return 0;
....
}

int recving_time(...) {
......
    fd_set readset;
select_again:
    set timeout value to structure *to*

    FD_ZERO(&readset);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &readset);
    readable = select(sockfd+1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &to);
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "readable is %d\n",readable); // **Why readable always be 0 although packets returned.** 
#endif
    if(readable < 0) {
        if(errno == EINTR)
            goto select_again;
    else {
        perror("select() error");
        exit(1);
    }   

    if(readable == 0)  {
        return -1;
    }
    ......
}
```

I'm not sure there is enough code here to understand what I am trying to saying. I will be very very appreciate if you can help me

Comment: You can't actually use port 0 -- if you bind to port 0, the kernel will allocate an unused port for you, and if the kernel sees packets sent to a non-existent port (such as 0), it will respond with a RST/ACK telling whoever sent it that there's no such port...

Comment: @ChrisDodd In fact, the program I want to write is similar to the command : hping3 -S 1.1.1.1  hping send syn packet to port 0. And get rst/ack reply to determin the host is online

Answer (score 0):

> Select() returns the number of ready descriptors that are contained in the descriptor sets, or -1 if an error occurred.  **If the time limit expires, select() returns 0.**

It would seem like your timeout (which you're not showing the setup of) is elapsing.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i discovered the reply from 1.1.1.1 returned back in 0.0003 second using wireshark

Comment: @MadFrog Since afaict the only time select returns 0 is on a timeout, it would seem that it times out in a shorter time than that.